# Histogram with ggplot2: change xticks, percentage of y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector `x`

```
 x = sample (1:3000, 20000, replace = T)
```

I tried to plot histogram of `x`

`ggplot() + aes(x)+ geom_histogram() + scale_x_log10() + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))  + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)`

[image]

I have two problems:

1. Why does the `y` axis showed 200%, 400%; it is impossible for a histogram.
2. How can I customize the x-ticks values. I want to display x-ticks as 0, 1, 2 ... 10, 20, 30 ... 10, 100.

Thanks a lot

Comment: For me your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned your code a bit. You included one `geom_histogram()` too much. Because of that the wired y-axis. The ticks you can control within the breaks argument of the scale functions.

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample (1:3000, 20000, replace = T))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + 
geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))  +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1,100,1000))
```

[image]